# selecting values after integer using substring

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table structure

```
create table #t(id int identity(1,1),street varchar(100))

insert into #t values('#100 church street'),('#102 vitalFinaly street'),('#101 teriyakei street')
```

I need output like this: (6 characters after integer)

```
id  (No column name)
1   church
2   vitalF
3   teriya
```

I tried this `select id,substring(street,6) from #t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Use Charindex](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)**

```
select id,substring(street,charindex(' ',street)+1,6) from #t
```

**[SEE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15459)**

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select 
  id, LEFT(SUBSTRING(Street, PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', Street), LEN(Street)), 6)
from #t
```

Answer (score 0):

Using one query

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(
    id BIGINT
    ,value NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

CREATE TABLE #t(id int identity(1,1),street varchar(100))
INSERT INTO #t 
OUTPUT
     INSERTED.Id
    ,LEFT(SUBSTRING(Inserted.Street, PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', Inserted.Street), LEN(Inserted.Street)), 6)
INTO @temp
VALUES ('#100 church street'), ('#102 vitalFinaly street'),('#101 teriyakei street')

SELECT *
FROM @temp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select RTRIM(LTRIM(LEFT(REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(street), PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(street)) - 1)),7)))
from #t
```

Please find the answer above.